# Cycle through PHP xml_parser and turn into array for easy reference

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML $result

```
    <Response>
      [.....]
       <Questions>
            <Question type="1" text="Which one of their favorite color?">
                <Answer correct="false">RED</Answer>
                <Answer correct="false">BLUE</Answer>
                <Answer correct="true">BLACK</Answer>
                <Answer correct="false">YELLOW</Answer>
            </Question>
            <Question type="2" text="What is their favorite food?">
                <Answer correct="false">PIZZA</Answer>
                <Answer correct="false">TACOS</Answer>
                <Answer correct="true">CAKE</Answer>
                <Answer correct="false">CHEESE</Answer>
            </Question>
            <Question type="3" text="Which person do they hate the most?">
                <Answer correct="false">Bill</Answer>
                <Answer correct="true">Jack</Answer>
                <Answer correct="false">Jammie</Answer>
                <Answer correct="false">Rick</Answer>
            </Question>                
        </Questions>
     </Response>
```

I know I would want to use...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

This will set $xml to the result of the SimpleXML object.  I would like to know the best way to cycle through these questions text so I can pull all the questions and add them to an Array, then easily reference them by type #, question text, and answer so I can just do

```
$QuestionText = $array["1"]["text"] //Which one is their favorite color?
$QuestionAnswer = $array["1"]["answer"] //BLACK
```

**EDIT** #1

While I haven't had a response back yet I been trying to figure it out myself and I've changed my method to an xml_parser...

```
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser,XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING,0);
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser,XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE,1);
xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $result, $vals,$index);
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);

   $newResArr = array();
        foreach($vals as $val)
        {
            if(($val['tag']=='Question'))   {   
                if(isset($val['attributes'])){
                    $type = $val['attributes']['type'];
                    $newResArr[$type]['text'] = $val['attributes']['text'];
                      //I assume a foreach needs to be put here?
                    }
                }
        }
```

Now I can reference the text by doing $newResArr['1']['text'] and I get what I want, however I don't know how to setup the foreach loop as described above to pull the answer if its attribute is set to true.

Comment: Do you really want to convert and access it in an array manner?

Comment: Lol, yes that's why I'm trying to do it :)

Comment: because simplexml_load_string returns an object and you can access object,though its not an array

Comment: right, but I don't want->to->reference->like->this

Comment: maybe my answer might help you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not saying this is the best answer, but I think this might help you.Please notice I have added `<text>` tag.

```
<?php 
$result ='<Response>
       <Questions>
            <Question type="1" text="Which one of their favorite color?">
                <Answer type="1" correct="false"><text>RED</text></Answer>
                <Answer type="1" correct="false"><text>BLUE</text></Answer>
                <Answer type="1" correct="true"><text>BLACK</text></Answer>
                <Answer type="1" correct="false"><text>YELLOW</text></Answer>
            </Question>
            <Question type="2" text="What is their favorite food?">
                <Answer correct="false"><text>PIZZA</text></Answer>
                <Answer correct="false"><text>TACOS</text></Answer>
                <Answer correct="true"><text>CAKE</text></Answer>
                <Answer correct="false"><text>CHEESE</text></Answer>
            </Question>
            <Question type="3" text="Which person do they hate the most?">
                <Answer correct="false"><text>Bill</text></Answer>
                <Answer correct="true"><text>Jack</text></Answer>
                <Answer correct="false"><text>Jammie</text></Answer>
                <Answer correct="false"><text>Rick</text></Answer>
            </Question>                
        </Questions>
     </Response>';
//Will convert Object data to array
function objectToArray($object){
     return json_decode(json_encode($object),true,512,0);
}

$xml = objectToArray(simplexml_load_string($result));

$array = $xml['Questions']['Question'][0];
$QuestionText = $array['@attributes']['text'];//Which one is their favorite color?
$QuestionAnswer = $array['Answer'];

foreach ($QuestionAnswer as $value) {
    if($value['@attributes']['correct'] == 'true'){
        echo 'The correct answer is '.$value['text'];
    } 
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
//You can also try to print the whole array
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
```

I hope that helps.